# Agregar columna como identificador

Tags: sql, sql-server

Un saludo, estoy trabajando con una tabla que no tiene una columna para poder identificar las filas es decir, no tiene un `identity` lo cual me causa un problema debido a que necesito obtener informacion de una columna de cada uno de los registros, alguien me podria indicar alguna funcion de sql que me agregue una culumna enumerando todos los registros y se puede utilizar en una condición `WHERE`.

esto es lo que tengo:

```
CVE_C         CVE_E
54231           1
54236           1
54237           1
54238           1
54240           1
```

esto es lo que necesito:

```
ID  CVE_C         CVE_E
1   57117            1
2   57116            1
3   57115            1
4   57114            1
5   57113            1
```

Comment: ahhh ok.. google... select rownum sql server...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero, crea una columna que tenga un numero. Aca elegi una particion segun lo que me parecio, pero en realidad deberias revisar cual te conviene.

```
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CVE_C) AS fila,
  CVE_C,
  CVE_E, 
FROM TuTabla
```

Y despues, mete ese select en otro select, y quedate con los registros que queres:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM
    (SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CVE_C) AS fila,
      CVE_C,
      CVE_E, 
    FROM TuTabla) As s
WHERE fila < 500
```

Ojo porque ROW_NUMBER() no asegura que en todas las corridas venga el mismo numero.